# native sql into an unmapped object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on modifying an existing application and I've decided to work with these 2 things.

My unmapped object is a simple object that consists of 2 integer properties:

```
public class EmployeeScore {

  private int id;
  private int score;
}
```

and I have a DAO which does the following:

```
public List<EmployeeScore> findEmployeeTotals(int regionId, int periodId) {
        DataVerify.greaterThan(regionId, 0, "Invalid Region id: Region Id cannot be zero");
        DataVerify.lessThan(regionId, 4, "Invalid Region id: Region id cannot be greater than 3");
        List<EmployeeScore> results = (List<EmployeeScore>) currentSession().createSQLQuery(
                "select n.EMP_ID, SUM(DISTINCT(nom.TOTAL_POINT)) from" +
                        " NOMINEE n join NOMINATION nom on nom.NOM_ID = n.NOM_ID" +
                        " join EMPLOYEE e on n.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID" +
                        " join COMPANY c on c.COMPANY_CODE = e.COMPANY_CODE" +
                        " join REGION r on r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID" +
                        " where nom.PERIOD_ID = :periodId" +
                        " AND nom.STATUS_ID = 2" +
                        " AND e.ISACTIVE = 1" +
                        " AND nom.CATEGORY_CODE != 'H'" +
                        " AND r.REGION_ID = :regionId" +
                        " group by n.EMP_ID")
                .setParameter("regionId", regionId)
                .setParameter("periodId", periodId)
                .list();

        return results;
    }
```

It's a huge query i know. I'm having problems on my tests and I assume because I'm not understanding how to apply these 2 correctly.

My test goes as follows:

```
@Test
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void testEmpScore() {
        NomPeriod period = nomPeriodHibernateDAO.findById(6);
        Region region = regionHibernateDAO.findById(1);
        List<EmployeeScore> results = winnerHibernateDAO.findEmployeeTotals(region.getId(), period.getId());
        results.toString();
        Assert.assertEquals(13, results.size());
    }
```

It should return 13 objects type `EmployeeScore` but instead it returns 0 so the test fails.

Can you point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong? I know it has to be something with my object seeing as it is not mapped but I have no way of mapping the score value or the id value since they reference different tables or aggregates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are querying for two integers and trying to interpret them as EmployeeScores.  Hibernate can do it but it will take a bit more work than that.

Assuming EmployeeScore has a constructor that takes two integers, you can try

```
 select new my.package.EmployeeScore(n.EMP_ID, SUM(DISTINCT(nom.TOTAL_POINT))) ...
```

You need to give it the full package path to your object.

Alternatively, by default, I think the query will return a List<Object[]>.  So you could iterate through these and form your employee scores manually.

```
  List<Object[]> results = query.list();
  List<EmployeeScore> scores = new LinkedList<EmployeeScore>();

  for (Object[] arr : results)
  {
     int id = (int) arr[0];
     int total = (int) arr[1];
     scores.add(new EmployeeScore(id, total));
  }
```

Comment: first one returns SQL Grammar Exception, I did include the full package path. The second one, i'm not sure but `Object[]` cannot be casted to `int`. :\ Also I'm casting the query to `List<EmployeeScore>` shouldn't it work anyway? Perhaps I'm missing an annotation or something?

Comment: http://www.nabeelalimemon.com/blog/2010/08/mapping-results-for-unmapped-entities/ this is more of what i'm talking about but how do i do the query without the xml?

Comment: you don't cast the whole Object[] to an int.  Each item in the array is an int - did you see the example I showed?  As far as the top example (new...), you actually have to use a regular Hibernate query, not a SQL query - my mistake.  If all of your entities are mapped (Employee, Company, Region, Nomination), then just go with the first option and change it to a Hibernate query

Comment: that's the reason I went with native sql, I cannot use the entities because for some reason they are eager fetched, and for the operations I am adding it would take a significant hit in performance :(

Comment: Whoops, as far as casting goes it should be casted to the non-primitive! so it should be `(Integer)`. Anyway that didn't work, the test still fails to fetch for some reason.

Comment: are you sure there is data and your joins are good?  if you run the query manually in your DB do you get results?

Comment: I think I'll resubmit with a new title since not fetching anything is worrysome. Things I've wondered are if I'm placing the query in the correct DAO (i've tried moving it around to no avail) but other than that I have zero clue. I changed the query a few times and ended up staying with what i have plus added `.addScalar("id").addScalar("score").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmployeeScore.class))`. Still didn't fetch anything. Data context is facing the correct database, I tested the application and all data is there. I also went back to recheck my query and it worked manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. Learned a few things.